# Sections division with right a bit rounded arrow css using border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Please suggest solution with using white borders]

Hi there, 
I need to have this kind sections division.
The problem is making the right arrow, but most important for me is to make it using borders, so I will be able to easily manipulate with it (e.g, change color, width etc.)
Is there any common solution? 
It is preferable to solve this using pure css, but if you know any other way to solve it, please suggest.

Comment: CSS does not support such shapes as far as I know. Maybe have a look at SVG if you want to avoid using images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
.menu-item::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -11px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 22px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: rotate( 45deg ) translateY( -50% );
    transform-origin: top;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-top: solid 2px rgb(236, 240, 241);
    border-right: solid 2px rgb(236, 240, 241);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/punb5k49/

you can make a rectangle and make it rotate 45deg and have border radius to have that kind of effect. not that perfect, but it's better then nothing

EDIT*

if you don't get what I mean, see this image and compare it with my jsfiddle

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check the solution here by using border property:-

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.bordr{
        height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
</style>
</head>
<div class="bordr">
</div>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xakdeyea/